# Pairing pre-test and post-test data in R

Tags: r

I have data of pre-test and post-test as in the following table:

```
      Test Participant_ID Score
1  pretest        part001    50
2 posttest        part001    70
3  pretest        part002    40
4  pretest        part003    40
5 posttest        part002    85
6  pretest        part004    60
7 posttest        part003    65
8 posttest        part004    75
```

I would like to pair the data to achieve something like this:

```
  Participant_ID Pretest Posttest
1        part001      50       70
2        part002      40       85
3        part003      40       65
4        part004      60       75
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? Please post attempted code so we can help with errors or undesired results. If you attempted nothing, please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) for a solution and give it an earnest try.

Comment: There are a dozen ways to do this in R, and questions like this have been answered a hundred times. See https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format